# cross compile libmodbus for ARM (BeagleBone Black)

Tags: linux, arm, beagleboneblack, modbus, toolchain

It's been several days I'm trying to cross-compile libmodbus to use it on my BeagleBone Black under Angstrom. I'm not really comfortable with Linux...
During the ./configure step, I can't find the good toolchain: I attempted with `./configure --host=` `arm`, `arm-linux`, `arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi`, `arm-none-linux-gnueabi`.

They all gave me the same error during compiling (minGW, Qt4):

```
error: skipping incompatible /home/ubuntu/Documents/developpement_Qt/Modbus/../libmodbus_arm/libmodbus.a when searching for -lmodbus
```

I even tried with arm-linux-gnueabihf, but the errors were even worse (here just the 2 first):

```
warning: ld-linux-armhf.so.3, needed by /home/ubuntu/Documents/developpement_Qt/Modbus/../libmodbusARM_linux-gnueabihf/libmodbus.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
error: /home/ubuntu/Documents/developpement_Qt/Modbus/../libmodbusARM_linux-gnueabihf/libmodbus.so uses VFP register arguments, Modbus does not
```

I'm now completely lost, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know if you even having the proper cross compilation tool chains set up?